# Checking a list

Tags: python, list, if-statement

```
if not bingo_num in player_1_num:
    print(bingo_num, "is not in", player1,"s list")
if not bingo_num in player_2_num:
    print(bingo_num, "is not in", player2,"s list")
```

I am making a bingo game and this is what my code looks like. I have tried

```
if not bingo_num in player_1_num:
    print(bingo_num, "is not in", player1,"s list")
```

and also

```
if bingo_num not in player_1_num:
    print(bingo_num, "is not in", player1,"s list")
```

But the output always says

**The number picked was  54**

***54 was found in John s list!***

**54 is not in Arjun s list**

***54 is not in John s list***

I was wondering how I could fix this mistake

**My whole code. I'm only a beginner so it may be messy and some parts may be unnecessary**

```
print("BINGO")
print("You must pick 6 numbers each in the range 1-100")
player_1_num = []
player_2_num = []
import random

player1 = input("Player 1 enter your name")
player2 = input("Player 2 enter your name")
print()
print("Time for ", player1, "to enter their numbers")
p1_num1 = int(input("Enter your first number"))
p1_num2 = int(input("Enter your second number"))
p1_num3 = int(input("Enter your third number"))
p1_num4 = int(input("Enter your fourth number"))
p1_num5 = int(input("Enter your fifth number"))
p1_num6 = int(input("Enter your sixth number"))
print()
print("Time for ", player2, "to enter their numbers")
p2_num1 = int(input("Enter your first number"))
p2_num2 = int(input("Enter your second number"))
p2_num3 = int(input("Enter your third number"))
p2_num4 = int(input("Enter your fourth number"))
p2_num5 = int(input("Enter your fifth number"))
p2_num6 = int(input("Enter your sixth number"))

player_1_num.append(p1_num1)
player_1_num.append(p1_num2)
player_1_num.append(p1_num3)
player_1_num.append(p1_num4)
player_1_num.append(p1_num5)
player_1_num.append(p1_num6)

player_2_num.append(p2_num1)
player_2_num.append(p2_num2)
player_2_num.append(p2_num3)
player_2_num.append(p2_num4)
player_2_num.append(p2_num5)
player_2_num.append(p2_num6)

print()
print()
print(player1, "your numbers are", player_1_num)
print(player2, "your numbers are", player_2_num)


while len(player_1_num) > 0 or len(player_2_num) > 0:
    print()
    input("Press enter to roll a number")
    bingo_num = random.randint(1,100)
    print("The number picked was ",bingo_num)
    if bingo_num in player_1_num:
        print(bingo_num, "was found in", player1,"s list!")
        player_1_num.remove(bingo_num)
    if bingo_num in player_2_num:
        player_2_num.remove(bingo_num)
        print(bingo_num, "was found in", player2,"s list!")
    if not bingo_num in player_1_num:
        print(bingo_num, "is not in", player1,"s list")
    if not bingo_num in player_2_num:
        print(bingo_num, "is not in", player2,"s list")
    if len(player_1_num) == 0:
        print(player1.upper()," HAS WON THE GAME")
        break
    if len(player_2_num) == 0:
        print(player2.upper()," HAS WON THE GAME")
        break
    print(player1, "your numbers are", player_1_num)
    print(player2, "your numbers are", player_2_num)


input("Press enter to exit")
```

Comment: paste all your code and your input

Comment: You need to give us sample data too. Most likely you are mixing strings and integer values.

Comment: How do you set the value of bingo_num??

Comment: The whole code is added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you check whether the number is in the list, *then you remove it* and then you check whether it's *not* in the list. And of course it is not, because you just removed it! Use `if/else` instead:

```
if bingo_num in player_1_num:
    print(bingo_num, "was found in", player1,"s list!")
    player_1_num.remove(bingo_num)
else:
    print(bingo_num, "is not in", player1,"s list")
```

(similar for player 2)

Comment: Thank you so much! So simple aha